# Unresolved extenral symbol - VC++ Linker

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, wdk, wdm

I'm using WDM to build a simple driver. (I have the latest WDK version and also the latest Visual Studio 2017 version installed).

The problem is that when it comes to building the solution, it just doesn't pass the linker and returns error 2019 ([click here to read more about it if you're not familiar with the error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019)) and it says _DriverEntry@8 is an unresolved external symbol referenced in function _GsDriverEntry@8 and the file is BufferOverflowFastFailK.lib.

Here is how I wrote my function's signature: `NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)`

Does somebody know how to fix it?

EDIT:
Here is my code:

```
#include "ntddk.h"

UNICODE_STRING DeviceName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\deviceone");
UNICODE_STRING SymLinkName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\deviceonelink");
PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = NULL;

void Unload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {
    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&SymLinkName);
    IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
    KdPrint(("Driver unloaded"));
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    NTSTATUS status;

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;

    status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, &DeviceName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &DeviceObject);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("Couldn't create device"));
        return status;
    }

    status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&SymLinkName, &DeviceName);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("Failed to create symbolic link"));
        IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
        return status;
    }

    KdPrint(("Driver has been loaded"));

    return status;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to add bufferoverflowfailk.lib as an additional dependency under the linker options in configuration properties and also in a pragma but still no success...

Comment: Not enough details in the question to answer the question. You can inspect the compile output obj that you're linking with with `dumpbin /symbols` to check how it's different from the expected symbol

Comment: You are not just supposed to declare but also define the function, you understand that, right?

Comment: Yes, I've defined the function.

Comment: Right, but that's not the compilation unit where you defined DriverEntry in, I was suggesting you dumpbin the compilation artifact from the cpp file that contains the DriverEntry function

Comment: Note the "UNDEF". Could you show all your code? Maybe there are some mangling issues...

Comment: @PeterT BufferOverflowFailK.lib: 00E 00000000 UNDEF notype () External | _DriverEntry@8 00F 00000000 SECT4 notype () External | _GsDriverEntry@8 
here is what I found in my file: 023 00000000 SECT8  notype ()    External     | ?DriverEntry@@YGJPAU_DRIVER_OBJECT@@PAU_UNICODE_STRING@@@Z (long __stdcall DriverEntry(struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *,struct _UNICODE_STRING *))
026 00000000 SECTC  notype       Static       | __guard_fids_?DriverEntry@@YGJPAU_DRIVER_OBJECT@@PAU_UNICODE_STRING@@@Z

Comment: right, so it's exporting the C++ calling convention and trying to import the C one, you're missing the `extern "C" ` in front

Comment: @PeterT it's name mangling (symbol decorarion), rather than calling conventions.

Comment: @IgorR. You're right the linker error occured because of the difference in name mangling. But I think extern "C" also affects the calling convention in addition to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're working with drivers it might be best to use in your headers:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

or just `extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ struct _DRIVER_OBJECT *DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath);` if this is the only function you need to export with the C calling convention and symbol decoration.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: There's a command line utility included with the WinSDK called **DUMPBIN.EXE**. One thing it's useful for is confirming that the exported functions 'exports' of your DLL are what they're supposed to be. Check out **DUMPBIN /EXPORTS**